# iPad doesn't go past the launchscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and my application recently got rejected from the app store due to the app not working on the iPad (even though I set it to iPhone only but apparently the rules have changed so now you have to support both?). My app works completely fine on the iPhone but when it comes to the iPad, it gets stuck on the launchscreen, I feel like this may be something really obvious, has anyone come across this?

Comment: Have you tested your application on an iPad or at least on the iPad simulator ?

Comment: Is this Universal App?

Comment: When you tested,did it run with launchscreen on iPad?

Comment: Do you use storyboard or XIB ?

Comment: Storyboard, and yes it's universal. It runs but just gets stuck on the launchscreen. Does the iPad need a separate iPad storyboard?